# Is it possible to get a hole in one on hole 18 on the Garden course?

Tags: tower-unite

Is there any way to get a Hole in One on Hole 18, of the Garden Course in minigolf in Tower Unite? I've looked all over and I cant find anything that would help me out here. I know it's possible, because you end up right next to the hole. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - *yes* its possible.  Here is [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Hgu9av_WEQ) of someone doing just this (with a ball that's wearing a chicken bucket hat). It's really a matter of hitting the ball with enough power and at the right angle in the beginning.  That's all there is to it.

It looks like in the beginning, the player shot slightly to the right at max power, and got a hole in one. It's definitely possible using a regular ball.

There appears to be a [Steam Guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=717708681) of all the  ways to get a hole in one on the maps.  They include screenshots of how much power and the angel needed.

*Your results may vary.*

Comment: It's not a cylinder, its a chicken bucket on his head. It's like a "hat".

Comment: I see that now. I know its possible to play as other shapes based off YouTube videos I've watched of Youtubers playing this.  Nice observation! I assume hats do not impact the way the ball rolls?

Comment: No they don't. They are, however, a way to "taunt" your friends... >:)

Comment: I think you might be thinking of `golf-with-friends`...

Comment: @Yoshi24517 I think you are right actually... kind of embarrassing - since I once answered an i[identification question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/287418/163757) that was asking if the game at hand was Golf with your Friends when it was really the gold min game in Tower Unite... you can tell I've never played either.